# best tool to take a backup from mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-backup

I am using mysql workbench for taking a backup/dump of my database hosted on Amazon RDS service. My database is very huge (about 8gib) and taking a 9-10 hours to download it from read-replica, mean while I am not able to see If download process is stuck or running. 
Is there any GUI tool available to take a backup fast and can also give details of which process is running like which table is downloading with its row details or percentage of total download. Mysql workbench is a good tool, but It hasn't show all the options given in 'mysqldump' command utility, and It is also very slow. and I also doubt about my data integrity. can someone explain me how it's work specially with data integrity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your 8GB database is by no means 'huge'. Second, I'm not clear on what you're trying to do? Amazon provides multiple ways for you to have backups.

From: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

**Q: Do I need to enable backups for my DB Instance or is it done automatically?**

By default and at no additional charge, Amazon RDS enables automated backups of your DB Instance with a 1 day retention period.